# Twilio - Showing Gif / media after body

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm playing around with the Twilio MMS API, and I'm wondering if there's a simple way to show a Gif attachment after the body text?

So far I've only been able to send the Gif before the text.

Comment: Please provide examples of your code and attempts to resolve your solution so the Stack Overflow community can provide you with assistance to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the behavior you are talking about.  I'm sure you've figured it out by now, but if not, here is a hack:

**Send a blank text file first**, which means put it last, as the files in this Twilio SMS/MMS (twiml too) are processed in reverse order.

### Twilio Functions Example (node.js)

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  var client = context.getTwilioClient();

  let dataMMS = {
           to: ['+15556667777'],  
         from: '+15551112222',  // your twilio num
         body:  'I am the body',
     mediaUrl:  [ 
 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/blog.invisionapp.com/uploads/2014/12/motion-example.gif', 
 'https://sepia-jaguar-8734.twil.io/assets/blank.csv'
                ],  
  contentType:  [
                  'image/gif', 
                  'text/csv'
                ]
  };

  client.messages.create(dataMMS).then(function(response){
    console.log('Message Sent : ' + response.status); 
    return callback(null, 200);  //response.status,  queued = good (200)
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log('An error is happening: ' + err); 
    return callback(null, err);
  });

}
```

### Extra:

This gif link was selected from a random link https://www.invisionapp.com/blog/7-tips-for-designing-awesome-gifs/.  It was selected because it was nice and small, ~25 kb.

In my **testing** with **Twilio** and my carrier, I found **gifs < ~100 kb worked** and if I remember correctly they are **not** run thru a **compress**or like png/jpegs.

**Note to Twilio employee:**  The Twilio public asset is in a dummy sub account, I'd be happy to replace it with an asset not related to me.

Oh yeah, make sure your urls have proper mime type encoding: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/accepted-mime-types
I think Twilio is forgiving for .jpg and .png , as they are run thru compressors...

**ps** This will give you an extra blank line in your text block, you can get rid of it.  Share your answer when you discover how, cause I've shared enough today.